# Git: Specify the remote and local branches

Tags: git

I want to use git commands with both, remote and local branch names. For example, instead of specify the origin with set-url origin, I want to use it on the command.

So, to use pull, it should looks like:

```
$ git pull origin dev
```

I see it in some places, but, I don't understand very well, I'm putting origin content on dev?

Maybe it's more accurate use:

```
$ git pull origin/dev dev
```

But, I can use it only if I'm in dev?

To see it more clear:

```
$git branch
*master
dev
$git pull origin/dev dev
```

This last would work as I expected, updating my dev branch with remote dev?

Comment: I recommend *avoiding* `git pull`. All `git pull` does is run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command. It's that *second* command that you might want to repeat for multiple branches—there's no need to repeat the `git fetch`. The *second* command makes sense on its own, without the weirdness of `git pull`. Do the fetch and the second command separately and things will begin to make sense.

Comment: @torek while in theory you are correct, I must say that in everyday life `git pull` is simply more convenient than typing `git merge FETCH_HEAD` every time and it doesn't hurt anyone (unless maybe you're on a satellite connection in an airplane where you are trying to save every possible byte :-))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But, I can use it only if I'm in dev?

**Yes.**

You can only update a local branch that is currently checked out. So `git pull` will always fetch from the given remote and branch (or the [tracking branch](https://git-scm.com/book/id/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches#_tracking_branches), if configured) and try to merge into the *currently checked out branch*.

In other words, in your case you have to `git checkout dev` and then `git pull origin dev` (to merge the *remote* branch `dev` from `origin` into your *local* branch `dev`).

The arguments after `git pull` refer to the remote and its branch that you want to merge in, *never* to a local branch.

See also the [`git pull` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull).